# Is CreateToolhelp32Snapshot function thread safe?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, process, thread-safety

As title, I can't find any information about whether `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot`, `Module32First` and `Toolhelp32ReadProcessMemory function` WinAPIs is thread-safe or not.

Dose anyone know about this? Or is there any way I can figure out whether those APIs are thread-safe?

MSDN: [Tool Help Functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686832(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those functions are threadsafe in the following way. Multiple threads can call `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot` and perform separate enumerations.

On the other hand, it's not a total free for all. You cannot share a single snapshot between threads and have the threads then perform unsynchronised operations on that snapshot. In fact, it would be folly to share a snapshot between multiple threads.